# How can one put $\langle z,z^* \rangle=\lambda d$?

Tags: functional-analysis

How can one put $$\langle z,z^*  \rangle=\lambda d$$ given $z \in W= M \oplus span(x_0)$, $z= u+\lambda x_0$, $u \in M$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$? $M \subset E$ is vector subspace, $E$ normed space, $x_0 \in E$.

Also $d=dist(x_0,M) >0$.

Comment: What is your definition of $z^*$?

Comment: @user10354138 It's an element in dual of $M$, i.e. it's a linear transformation $M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: My particular problem is that since it's not assumed to be an inner product space, then I don't even know what $\langle , \rangle$ refers to.

Answer (score 0):

$\langle z, z^{*} \rangle$ is just another notation for $z^{*}(z)$, not to be confused with an inner product. Here they are defining  a linear functional on $W$. Every element of $W$ can be written uniquely as $u+\lambda x_0$ and $z^{*}(u+\lambda x_0)$ is defined as $\lambda d$. This gives you a linear functional om $W$ such that which is $0$ on $M$ and has the value $d$ at $x_0$.

Comment: Can you refer to where this notation is introduced, for example? Does it make any assumptions about linearity etc? Or just "some function that we apply to"?

Comment: How does one know that there exists a $z^*$ s.t. $z*(u+\lambda x_0)=\lambda d$?

Comment: The notation comes from the concept of pairing. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_pair

Comment: The function $z^{*}$ is obviously well defined and linear on $W$.

Comment: Yes, but how does one know that the desired kind of $z^*$ exists. Since $d=\inf_{u \in M} \|x_0-u\|$, what kind of function is $z^*$?

Comment: $d$ is just a constant in this definition.

Comment: How does one know that $u+ \lambda x_0$ is constant? It could be a vector.